# Processing of Q_OBJECT in legacy non qmake build?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have a legacy build that doesn't use qmake but I'd like to add QUdpSocket and connect it with a signal and a slot. I have a single class that uses Q_OBJECT. What do I need to do to properly process the Q_OBJECT directive if I want signals and slots to be available but I am not using qmake.

Can I just substitute the original myclass.h file with the output of the "$moc myclass.h"? Or is the output in addition to the original file?

Is this the likely new make directives?

```
m_myclass.h : myclass.h
    moc myclass.h > m_myclass.h
```

Comment: use cmake instead of qmake

Comment: @eyllanesc: using CMake every day, if we are talking about simple Qt projects I'd take `qmake` over `cmake` every moment - it is way simpler (= less stuff that can go wrong) and has better integration with Qt tools.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I do not say that cmake is simpler or more reliable than qmake, but that cmake is a good option but implementing a makefile manually is heavier than the qmake or cmake.

Comment: @eyllanesc: that's for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MOC actually generates .cpp files to be compiled along with the rest of the project; so, that would be more something like:

```
moc_myclass.cpp: myclass.h
    moc myclass.h > moc_myclass.cpp

moc_myclass.o: moc_myclass.cpp
    g++ ${CFLAGS} moc_myclass.cpp -o moc_myclass.o // whatever
```

and then add `moc_myclass.o` to the linking step of your final executable.